# $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology. If $\overline{X}\cap\overline{X^c} = \emptyset$ then $X=\mathbb{R}$ or $X=\emptyset$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, real-numbers

I'm asked to prove that, with the usual topology for $\mathbb{R}$, if the intersection of the closure of a set with the closure of the complement of the same set equals the empty set, then it must be the case that such set is either the empty set or the real numbers. This is:

If  $\overline{X}\cap\overline{X^c} = \emptyset$ then $X=\mathbb{R}$ or  $X=\emptyset$.

Assuming $X\neq\emptyset$, I'm struggling with the "complicated" block of the proof, this is that $\mathbb{R}\subset X$. So far my approach has been a proof by contradiction, taking $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and assuming $x\notin X$. Thus $x\in X^c$ and, since $X^c \subset \overline{X^c}$, $x$ is contained in the open set $\overline{X^c}$. Moreover, by hypothesis, if $x \in \overline{X^c}$ then $x \notin \overline{X},\ x\in\overline{X}^{\ c}$.

Additionaly, given that $\overline{X}\cap\overline{X^c} = \emptyset$, I obtain $\overline{X^c} \subset \overline{X}^{\ c}$.

Do you have any thoughts on how to proceed from here towards a contradiction? Or is there a more elegant way to prove this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You forgot to say you were talking about $R$ with the usual topology. The space matters. I inferred it, but had to waste a bit of time.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor my apologies, you are totally right. Thank you for the edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT**

I would start with noticing that $\overline{X} = \text{int}(X)\cup\partial X$ and $\overline{X^{c}} = \text{ext}(X)\cup\partial X$.

Consequently, $\overline{X}\cap\overline{X^{c}} = \partial X = \varnothing$.

Now it remains the question: what are the subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ with no boundary points?

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Suppose that $\operatorname{cl}(X)\cap\operatorname{cl}(\Bbb R\setminus X)=\varnothing$. Clearly

$$\operatorname{cl}(X)\cup\operatorname{cl}(\Bbb R\setminus X)\supseteq X\cup(\Bbb R\setminus X)=\Bbb R\,,$$

so $\operatorname{cl}(X)=\Bbb R\setminus\operatorname{cl}(\Bbb R\setminus X)$. And $\operatorname{cl}(\Bbb R\setminus X)$ is a closed set, so its complement, $\operatorname{cl}(X)$, is open. In other words, $X$ is clopen (both open and closed); what are the only clopen subsets of $\Bbb R$? (This is especially easy if you know that $\Bbb R$ is connected.)